# Sorting games list vertically

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array loading a list of games. Currently it is being sorted like this:

```
A   B    C
D   E    F
```

Now I would like to sort it like the following:

```
A  D
B  E
C  F
```

How can I do this please? I have tried using chunk and even slice but no success.

Comment: Post the code that you've tried so that we can tell you what is amiss

Comment: Think about it mathematically. What you're trying to do is a simple [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple slice and transpose:

```
a = %w{A B C D E F}
p a.each_slice(3).to_a.transpose

# => [["A", "D"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "F"]]
```

The each_slice(3) will need to be adjusted for the dimensions of the source array and final matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Spot on comment by @Jan

```
input = "A   B    C\nD   E    F"
output = input.split(/\n+/).map{|e| e.split(/\s+/)}.transpose
p output
```

Output:

```
[["A", "D"], ["B", "E"], ["C", "F"]]
```

and if what you are provided is just an array as you mentioned, it's even easier

```
input = [ ["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"] ]
output = input.transpose
p output
```